# Set MaxLength of Textarea to 50 Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, squarespace

I'm trying to set the character limit of a **textarea** field to 50 characters using only javascript. I CANNOT directly edit the HTML of the **textarea** field.

Here is the code I've attempted:

### HTML

```
<textarea class="field-element " id="textarea-yui3" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

### Javascript

```
<script>
document.getElementById("textarea-yui3").maxLength = "50";
</script>
```

This is not working. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: If i put your code into a snippet, it works.

Comment: No, because it requires that I'm able to add onkeypress="return imposeMaxLength(event, this, 110);" to my textarea tag, which I'm not able to do.

The solution has to be entirely done in javascript without editing the textarea directly. If that requires injecting the onkeypress event then so be it.

Comment: `maxLength` should be `maxlength` (small case). also try using setAttribute('maxlength', "50");

Comment: @MohamedMufeed Looks like `maxLength` to me on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement), plus as already mentioned, it works for me, which wouldn't be the case, if it was a typo.

Comment: Ah sorry, I mistaken the element’s attribute with the object’s property. The attribute is what: in small case. so, `.setAttribute('maxlength', '50')` whould have been fine.

Answer (score 2):

Add function in textarea on event onkeypress. Code as follow:

```js
let textarea = document.querySelector("form div.form-item textarea.field-element");
textarea.maxLength = "50";
textarea.onkeypress = function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 8) { return true; }
   return this.value.length < this.maxLength;
};
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <form data-form-id="5d276a629196ad00019f6f19" data-success-redirect="" autocomplete="on" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1607975626173_414">      
        <div class="field-list clear" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1607975626173_413">
              <div id="textarea-yui_3_17_2_1_1562863586015_217028" class="form-item field textarea">                
            <label class="title" for="textarea-yui_3_17_2_1_1562863586015_217028-field">
              Enclosure card message or Coments              
            </label>
                <textarea class="field-element " id="textarea-yui_3_17_2_1_1562863586015_217028-field"></textarea>
              </div>
            <div id="select-yui_3_17_2_1_1562863586015_217961" class="form-item field select">                
            <label class="title" for="select-yui_3_17_2_1_1562863586015_217961-field">
              Gift wrap              
            </label>
                <select id="select-yui_3_17_2_1_1562863586015_217961-field" name="select-yui_3_17_2_1_1562863586015_217961-field">                  
                    <option value="General">General</option>                  
                    <option value="Female gift">Female gift</option>                  
                    <option value="Male gift">Male gift</option>                  
                    <option value="Holiday / Seasonal">Holiday / Seasonal</option>                  
                </select>
              </div>
        </div>
      <div data-animation-role="button" class="form-button-wrapper">
        <input class="button sqs-system-button sqs-editable-button" type="submit" value="Add To Cart">
      </div>      
      <div class="hidden form-submission-text"></div>
      <div class="hidden form-submission-html" data-submission-html=""></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code updated!

Comment: and if they paste?

Comment: This did not work. This is where the textarea is setup. If you go to pridescrossingconfections.com/products/turtles , select any size, select any choice, and then click add to cart. A window pops up that allows you to add a message. This is the box I'm trying to limit the characters of.

Comment: @FeliciaSantos, code updated!

Comment: This is similar to the solutions presented on the duplicate I added to the question as the first comment.

Comment: This looks great, but it isn't working. I wonder if it has to do with the form being in a lightbox.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I tried that solution before asking this question but it did not work for me.

Comment: @FeliciaSantos, Even with the updated code was not it? What framework are you using?

Comment: @FeliciaSantos "That solution" There are 15 answers on the question. If there are other extenuating circumstances not in your question, please ask another question with all information needed.

Comment: @RenatoSant'Anna Yes, I used your updated code. This is a Squarespace site.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", event => {
        document.getElementById('textarea-yui3').addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
            let texLen = document.getElementById('textarea-yui3').value.length;
            let kc = event.keyCode;
            if (texLen >= 50 && (kc === 32 || (kc >= 48 && kc <= 57) || (kc >= 65 && kc <= 90)))
                event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

By checking keyCode, you could let all other editor keys work fine, such as ins, delete, backspace, f5, ...

If you are adding textarea dynamicallyto the page, then you should add eventListener after adding textarea to DOM, not on pageLoad event.

Comment: Hmm it didn't seem to work. This is where it is setup. If you go to https://www.pridescrossingconfections.com/products/turtles , select any size, select any choice, and then click add to cart. A window pops up that allows you to add a message. This is the box I'm trying to limit the characters of.

Comment: And if they paste?

Comment: @FeliciaSantos the id textarea is different. I will change my code to complete your problem.

Comment: I know. I just shorthanded the ID here so it wasn't so wordy. I updated your code to reflect the actual ID and it still didn't work.

Comment: if you are adding textarea dynamically, then you should addeventListener after adding textarea to DOM, not on pageLoad event
@FeliciaSantos

Comment: @FeliciaSantos, I will update code for id in element.

Answer (score -2):

It's because the property `maxLength` receives a `Number` not a `String`, this should do the tick: `document.getElementById("textarea-yui3").maxLength = 50;`

Comment: This didn't work, unfortunately :(

Comment: No, JavaScript will automatically coerce the string to a number.